# Reference specific object in custom object array, and change value

Tags: arrays, swift, custom-object

So I have the class Caddy:

```
class Caddy{

        var caddyName: String
        var phoneNumber: Int
        var email: String
        var password: String
        var caddyRank: String
        var caddyLocation: Int
        var proPic: UIImage  
}
```

I have a array of these custom objects, `caddyList`.

I need to reference a specific object in the array using a string `caddyName`.

I then need to change a value of that specific object, specifically the `caddyLocation` value.

How can I accomplish this using Swift 2.0?

Answer (score 0):

If order is not important to you, you should use a [Dictionary](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html) of Caddys instead of an array of Caddys. That would allow O(1) access to any category in the collection. It also is easy to access and modify an object with swift.

```
// Assume you have two Caddy objects, caddy1 and caddy2
// Create the dictionary
caddies = [caddy1.caddyName: caddy1, caddy2.caddyName: caddy2]  // eg, etc...

// Access and change the caddies location (if the name has a match)
caddies["Bob"]?.caddyLocation = 2
```

If you want to know when the caddy actually exists and a modification was made, then wrap it in an `if let`.

```
let bobCaddyName = "Bob"
if let _ = caddies[bobCaddyName] {
  caddies[bobCaddyName]?.caddyLocation = 2
}
```